# accountsd is takin so much memory

Tags: keychain

for some reason my accountsd is taking so much memory. even though I have a 16 mb macbook pro.. If I kill that process it keeps on opening back up again.. ideas? [image]

Comment: I don't see any memory reports. But the CPU consumption is pretty high. Does the same happens after restart?

Comment: yeah this is exactly after restart.. I also just got a gigantic 4k monitor

Comment: For problems with high `accountsd` CPU use, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182059