# accountsd eating up all CPU resources when wireless has no internet connectivity

Tags: mail.app, catalina, bug, cpu, accounts

it's a shame that the OS have degraded to this levels of breakage and bugs.

There's a way to stop `accountsd` from eating up all my CPU when I'm without internet access in a wireless connection for LAN only?

[image: accountsd eating up all my cores]

So there's any workaround for this? I don't even expect a fix from Apple anymore.

Many friends are ditching OS integrated internet accounts to avoid this issues, but I really don't want to go this path, only if it became my last resource.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the accountsd process eating so much CPU?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182059/why-is-the-accountsd-process-eating-so-much-cpu)

Comment: It's not eating up memory, and it's not duplicate from. It's an issue within the same software but not related on the thread. Since on the thread is vague and on macOS 10.10; we are five years later with a well defined issue in a specific condition, and not under normal usage like on the linked thread.

Comment: No, the only common denominator was really the connection without WAN access. I've double checked the answers on the linked thread and it seems to be Gmail related. In fact I do have a Gmail account added on Internet Accounts. But it's only for mail, some folks says about calendar specific. I can try removing the Gmail account completely and see what happens.

Comment: @ankii Mail was crashed LOL. Take a look at the picture. I'll double check and edit the question.

Comment: It seems to be stuck/ beachball. All I see is it being open in BG, and  its high CPU usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lucky move and being able to contact Apple, I've sent some logs to the chief engineer of `accountsd` and on the release of macOS 10.15.4 this bug was solved.

So the fix would be upgrade to at least 10.15.4.

Comment: Still have the bug on 10.15.5

Comment: Still have it on 10.15.7

Comment: Ok, I just fixed this by signing out my Apple ID by going to SystemPreferences -> Apple ID. I don't have enough reputation to post this solution, but found it here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/182059/why-is-the-accountsd-process-eating-so-much-cpu

Comment: @SandervandenOord the issue does not seems to be related. I've seen this link when this issue affected me and I didn't worked ou my case. So it's the same issue, but the origin of the issue may not be the same.

Answer (score 3):

After various attempts at disabling and logging out of iCloud accounts on the device, in the end a reset of Keychain fixed it:

Keychain Access -> Preferences -> Reset My Default Keychains

Comment: Thanks: this one (Keychain Access -> Preferences -> Reset My Default Keychains) worked for me. However, be aware that all passwords for mail accounts need to be re-entered.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to have fixed it for me is re-enabling mail access to spotlight:

System preferences -> Spotlight -> "Mail & messages"