# Suddenly the fan of my Mac Mini starts to run as crazy - Possible reason / elimination?

Tags: macos, catalina, mac-mini

Just started my Mac Mini 15 minutes ago. Suddenly the fan started to work and the sound is clearly hearable. Normally the machine works quietly.
I took a look into the processes-table and found that there is a process "accountsd". The "Accounts daemon" perhaps ...

[image]

Might the "accountsd"-process be related to the annoying fan-trouble?

**What can be the reason of the described behaviour, out of the blue?**

**What can one do against it?**

Here are the OS-specs:

[image]

Comment: accountsd is part of the security framework that controls what you access - I have had the same issue on a Mac Mini (2012) on and off since Sierra and now control my fan with *Macs Fan Control*

Comment: Try to reset the NVRAM. This solved it for me: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/402079/390499

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the problem, meanwhile.

Here's what worked for me: In the "System-Preferences" it was demanded to update the Apple-ID.

[image]

[image]

After doing so, I shutdown the machine. Then started it again.

The problem is now gone. The accountsd-process is still there in the processes-table, but the use of system-capacity is back to normal.

Comment: I have the same thing on iPad but it doesn't seem to go away.